# Maximum non-PV work and reversibility at constant temperature and pressure

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, free-energy

When we talk about systems at constant temperature and pressure, maximum amount of non-PV work can be extracted if process is carried reversibly and in that case it is equal to change in Gibbs energy of the system. When system does work, Gibbs energy of system decreases and vice versa.

When we have chemical reaction in the system (for example electrochemical process in galvanic cell) than Gibbs energy of the system changes because of that reaction.

Basically, what does it mean to carry chemical reaction reversibly or irreversibly? Does carrying reaction reversibly mean that system is at chemical equilibrium where reaction Gibbs energy equals zero?

If so, how can we extract any non-PV work (in our case non - PV work is electrical work since we are talking about galvanic cell) if system/reaction is already at equilibrium?

Electromotive force of cell is zero at equilibrium and such cell can't be used to power anything (electric motor for example).